# Opening two files in same application instance

Tags: c#, windows, file

So I have an application that has a special file type .rxml associated to it. 
If the application is already running and I open  one of these files, it opens a new instance of the application. Is there a way to make the file open in the same application instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, roughly-speaking, a new instance of the application will be launched, detect the existing instance and pass information to it, e.g. the path to the new file to be opened.  You have a few options for this task, including WCF and Remoting.